# How to loop through a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with the following schema:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| country_dest | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type         | varchar(56) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| version      | varchar(56) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

For every `country_dest` there will be several `type` - business, tourist, etc (but each country_dest may have different or totally unique types).

I want to make sure that for every type, in every country there is a particular value of `version` (the same value eg 'complete').

So for instance:

```
+----+--------------+------------+----------+
| id | country_dest | type       | versions |
+----+--------------+------------+----------+
|  1 |            8 | business   | single   |
|  2 |            8 | business   | complete |
|  3 |            8 | tourist    | single   |
|  4 |            8 | tourist    | complete |
|  5 |            8 | diplomatic | single   |
|  6 |           14 | business   | single   |
|  7 |           14 | business   | complete |
|  8 |           14 | private    | single   |
|  9 |           31 | business   | double   |
| 10 |           31 | business   | complete |
+----+--------------+------------+----------+
```

If that was the table contents, then the query would return that:

country_dest: 8 with type: diplomatic, and 
country_dest: 14 with type: private

don't have the `complete` value.

Output should be:

```
+---------------+---------------+
| country_dest  |      type     |
+---------------+---------------+
|             8 |   diplomatic  |
|            14 |   private     |
+---------------+---------------+
```

It seems like it would be great to loop through this in a for loop, but that's not how it's done. I've tried lots of solutions but I can't get them to work and I'm sure there must be a tried and tested way of doing this. This is my latest effort:

```
SELECT form_dest, form_vtype, form_ispack FROM _forms f
WHERE form_dest IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT dest.form_dest FROM _forms) dest
AND form_vtype IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT form_vtype FROM _forms as type)
AND NOT EXISTS  
    (SELECT * FROM _forms 
    WHERE f.form_dest = dest.form_dest 
    AND f.form_type = type.form_type 
    AND f.form_ispack = "Yes")
```

but I get errors.

Grateful for any help on this. Cheers.

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired output you'd like to get  - Kind of like your table's example content. It'll make your question much easier to understand.

Comment: Do you want to find the "missing" rows or insert them in one query?

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your comments. I've updated my original post to show desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `NOT EXISTS` should be enough to get the results you require.

To get the entire `_forms` record, you can wrap the statement into a subselect and join it again with `_forms`.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  country_dest
        , type
FROM    _forms invalid
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (        
          SELECT  country_dest
                  , type
          FROM    _forms valid
          WHERE   versions = 'complete'
                  AND valid.country_dest = invalid.country_dest
                  AND valid.type = invalid.type
        )          
GROUP BY
        country_dest
        , type
```

or equivalent using a `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT country_dest
        , type
FROM    _forms invalid
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (        
          SELECT  country_dest
                  , type
          FROM    _forms valid
          WHERE   versions = 'complete'
                  AND valid.country_dest = invalid.country_dest
                  AND valid.type = invalid.type
        )
```

#### Test script (SQL Server)

```
;WITH _forms (country_dest, type, versions) AS (
  SELECT  8, 'business', 'single'
  UNION ALL SELECT  8, 'business', 'complete'
  UNION ALL SELECT  8, 'tourist', 'single'
  UNION ALL SELECT  8, 'tourist', 'complete'
  UNION ALL SELECT  8, 'diplomatic', 'single'
  UNION ALL SELECT 14, 'business', 'single'
  UNION ALL SELECT 14, 'business', 'complete'
  UNION ALL SELECT 14, 'private', 'single'
  UNION ALL SELECT 31, 'business', 'double'
  UNION ALL SELECT 31, 'business', 'complete'
)
SELECT  country_dest
        , type
FROM    _forms f
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (        
          SELECT  country_dest
                  , type
          FROM    _forms f2
          WHERE   versions = 'complete'
                  AND f2.country_dest = f.country_dest
                  AND f2.type = f.type
        )          
GROUP BY
        country_dest
        , type
```

Comment: I think you need a `GROUP BY country_dest, type`

Comment: @ypercube - that was my first thought to but it is not necessary. I have added a testscript to demonstrate that.

Comment: If you had another row: `(14,'private', 'double')` though, it would be needed, right?

Comment: @Lieven - Thanks very much for this. It works great. I was convinced that I would have to use `DISTINCT` to make sure that the `country_dest`, `type` combinations were unique.

Comment: @ypercube - ah, I see. You mean the end result. I have added the `GROUP BY`. (note to OP: a DISTINCT would be the same).

Comment: @Lieven - Got it. Although shouldn't that be `GROUP BY country_dest, type`? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Leven - It was an extremely small contribution on my part ;) Thanks for your v. detailed and clear answer.